# Symfony 6 error in ManyToOne ORM relationship

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm currently facing an unexplained problem with my app written in PHP 8 and symphony 6.

I have two entities : E1 and E2.

In the class E1 I have the attribute :

```
#[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: \App\Entity\E2::class)]
#[ORM\JoinColumn]
private ?\App\Entity\E2 $e2 = null;
```

When I'm trying to access any page in the app, I have the following error :

```
Cannot assign Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection to property App\Entity\E1::$e2 of type ?App\Entity\E2
```

This error appears only when I try to access the pages quickly. Sometimes, a simple refresh resolves the problem.

I can't fin the origin of this error, since there is no explanation on why symphony is trying to assign a collection to a simple variable

I tried changing the definition of the variable "$e2" and deleting the "null"" assignment.

I tried adding logs but no anomaly appeared

thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Could you provide the error stack trace ?  it would help to see where the `$e1->e2 = new ArrayCollection()` is called.